# Core Data Modelling from SQL

Tags: swift, core-data, data-modeling

I am about to start using Core Data for the first time and I'm trying to make sure that my data model is decent before I get too far into it and realizing it's not. I am experienced in SQL and assumed (wrongly is seems) that Core Data was SQLite under a different name. I have read that a big failing of Core Data projects by newcomers is that they try to apply RBMS concepts into Core Data and that isn't necessarily the best way to go. I have mocked up a little SQL schema I was looking to use in this test project. But unsure how it should be altered to fit more appropriately with core data? So if anyone could give some pointers for my scenario that would be great

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget persistence (putting it on disk). How would you model this in just in-memory data structures? That's typically very close to how you would model it in Core Data. Core Data is an object graph persistence engine. If your object graph were small enough to fit in memory, in principle you wouldn't need Core Data at all (that's not completely true; Core Data has some other features, but allowing you to efficiently deal with a massive object graph is the headline one).

There are a few differences in Core Data, such as every relationship requiring an inverse (so if Player has a team relationship, then Team should have a players relationship). But basically, model it the way you'd model objects, because that's what they are.

So I don't completely understand some of your model, but a generic "players are on teams and teams have games and games are in a season," I'd imagine a (simplified) model along these lines:

```
class Player: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var team: Team?  // 0..1 relationship
}

class Team: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var players: Set<Player> // 0..*
    @NSManaged var homeGames: Set<Game> // Inverse for homeTeam (See more below)
    @NSManaged var awayGames: Set<Game> // Inverse for awayTeam

    // There are more powerful and efficient ways to do this, but a simple convenience example
    var games: Set<Game> { return homeGames + awayGames }
}

class Game: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var homeTeam: Team
    @NSManaged var awayTeam: Team
    @NSManaged var season: Season
    @NSManaged var date: NSDate
}

class Season: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var games: Set<Game> // Note again the inverse relationship
}
```

I made it homeTeam/awayTeam so that it was easy to enforce exactly two teams. But you could also do it this way:

```
class Team: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var players: Set<Player> // 0..*
    @NSManaged var games: Set<Game> // Many to many relationship
}

class Game: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var teams: Set<Team> // Many to many relationship
    @NSManaged var season: Season
    @NSManaged var date: NSDate
}
```

Many-to-many relationships aren't a magical thing that you have to create intermediates for in Core Data. They're just "to many" relationships where the inverse is also "to many." There's no need for keys or any of that. It's all just objects. That's how you think about Core Data for the most part.

(I've written this in a form that hopefully makes sense even though it's not absolutely legal in Xcode 7.3. The types of the relationships will be an untyped `NSSet`. This is all drastically improved in Xcode 8 and iOS 10 and you get strong types, but I haven't done enough work there to be certain if this is quite the syntax or not.)

Comment: Thanks Rob, that's helpful to me. I wasn't quite sure how things like  intermediates and keys were done. But had read that they were often areas people get wrong. So this is a great answer! :-)

Comment: This may require another question, so let me know. Just thinking more about this and I follow it, but how would you account for changing data over history. So say player A plays for team A for one year, but next year he plays for team B. If you searched back over time presumably his data would all be games for Team B as that's his current team. Another example, is say player A doesn't play in some games and I wanted to track how much they'd played. How without an intermediate would you do that?

Comment: It's an interesting question, and isn't unlike the problem you'd have in a database, as well. I'd probably rename player.team to player.currentTeam, and then I'd probably give Games both two teams and two TeamRosters, where each TeamRoster is a collection of actual Players.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. My absolute last question. How in the Core Data Modeller would I set up an attribute to be a set/dictionary/array? Collection types don't seem to be available

Comment: You add a Relationship and make it "to many." That will always be a Set. There aren't any other good collection choices (OrderedSet exists, but is very buggy and unreliable). If you want an order, you'll have to add a property to sort on (sometimes just an integer called "order".) You cannot have a collection of non-entities. If you want a collection, it must be a relationship. (There are tricks around that, like using a ValueTransformer, but they're limited in power.)

Comment: Thanks I would have never have worked this all out. So I'm taking it that I can't have a dictionary with <playername: minutesPlayed>   Which is where I was heading after your help with this

Comment: You'd definitely have to compute that dictionary by walking over the model. If those kinds of "slice the data" questions are very common in your use case, then you may want to consider using a database to store the records. Core Data is all about being a persistent object graph. It doesn't have the depth of calculation tools that are available in raw SQL. If each player is winding up with thousands of "Period" entities attached to them, I would probably do that part in a database (I've done it in Core Data; it works, but it's not as powerful).

Comment: There is no rule that says that if you use Core Data everything has to be in Core Data, or if you use a database, everything has to be there.